# how to code to find the percentile of a distribution when i know the SPECIFIC cumulative distribution function in R?

Tags: r, quantile

For a given $k_2$ and $n_2$ ,how to solve  the percentile of a distribution when I know this cumulative distribution function

[image: SPECIFIC cumulative distribution function]

I wonder if anyone could help write down the R code to solve this problem, THX!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: i have no clue how to start with it in R, so no codes for information sorry, anyone help

Comment: Is that F(...) thing is pdf or cdf? I'm hesitated that notate pdf with capital F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter that parameters `k1`, `k2`, `n1`, `n2` are fixed or not.
As it said in text, I proceed with `F` as pdf of beta distributions. `stats::integrate` function helps integrate function.

```
cdf <- function(t, k1, k2, n1, n2){
  dummy_func <- function(x) {
    pbeta(x+t, k1 + .5, n1 - k1 + .5) * x^(k2 - .5) * (1 - x)^(n2 - k2 - .5)
  }
   1/beta(k2 + .5, n2 - k2 + .5) * integrate(dummy_func, lower = 0, upper = 1)$value
  
}
```

And then it's not that precise but let `x = seq(-0.9,1,by = 0.001)` is vector of sequence from `-0.9` to `1` by `0.001`. In this case, I let support of this function as (0.9,1). We can obtain cumulative probability for elements in `x` with `y <- sapply(x, function(t) cdf(t,1,1,1,1))`. Then find quantile whatever you want, for example like 80%, let `z <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))` then `z$x[which.min(abs(z$y - 0.8))]` = `0.281` will be an answer.

Comment: I really appreciate it. it  exactly  find the right percentile provided in the text!

Comment: @williamzhang I'm glad it helped :D